# File upload in net core, do I need to disable model binding when upload file to Api controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

According to the official example (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-5.0#uploading-large-files-with-streaming), I need to disable form model binding when upload files to a **mvc controller**, which inherits `Controller`, using `DisableFormValueModelBindingAttribute`. I wonder whether I need it for my **api controller**, which inherits `ControllerBase`. I could not find any where for that information.

If I do need to disable form model binding, how can I do this?